# Finding Min/Max/Saddle Points When Hessian Is Not Invertible

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-2x^2+4xy-2y^2$$

I have found out that $(\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$ and $(\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$ are minimum point, but for $(0,0)$ I get that the Hessian is

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
-4 & 4 \\
4 & -4 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Which has determinant of zero, what should I do to determine which point is it?

Comment: Have searched for similar posts here? There seem to be quite a few of them.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the path $y=0$ and got $(0,0)$ is maximum and and $x=y$ and got that the second derivative test was inclusive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(x,x)=2x^4$ and $f(x,-x)=2x^2(x^2-4)$. Hence, for $x \ne 0$ in a "small" neighborhood of $0$ we have

$f(x,-x) <0 =f(0,0) < f(x,x)$.

Thus $(0,0)$ is a saddle point.